# The order of output changes when the input is the same, why?

Tags: java, oop, output

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://kth.kattis.com/problems/genealogical and the only testcase there for me works perfect. But if I instead write the third birth line on the first line and the first birth line on the third line, it prints this: http://puu.sh/kJdBU/dcd693e466.png which is in the wrong order. Do anyone know why and how I can fix this if this is my code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Genealogical {

private static List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        String firstLine = input.nextLine();
        String[] splitted = firstLine.split(" : ");
        if (splitted.length == 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (firstLine.contains("BIRTH") && splitted.length >= 2) {
            String childName = splitted[0].substring(6);
            if (splitted.length == 4) {
                birth(childName, splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
            }

        }

        else if (firstLine.contains("DEATH")) {
            if (!firstLine.contains(" : ")) {
                if (persons.size() > 0)
                    persons.get(persons.size() - 1).kill(
                            firstLine.substring(6));
            } else {
                String name = splitted[0].substring(6);
                getPerson(name).kill(splitted[1]);
            }
        }

        else if (firstLine.contains("ANCESTORS")) {
            String name = splitted[0].substring(10);

            Person ancestor = getPerson(name);
            for (Person p : persons) {
                if (p.getName().equals(name) || p.used) {
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    p.used = true;
                    ancestor.addAncestors(p);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (firstLine.contains("DESCENDANTS")) {

            String name = splitted[0].substring(12);

            Person descendant = getPerson(name);
            for (Person p : persons) {
                if (p.getName().equals(name) || p.used) {
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    p.used = true;
                    descendant.addDescendants(p);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (firstLine.contains("QUIT")) {
            if (persons.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = persons.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    Person p = persons.get(i);

                    if (p.getAncestors().size() > 0) {
                        printAncestor(p);

                    }

                    if (p.getDescendants().size() > 0) {
                        printDescendant(p);
                    }

                }
            }

            System.exit(0);

        }
    }

}

public static void printAncestor(Person p) {
    System.out.println("ANCESTORS of " + p.getName());
    for (Person ancestor : p.getAncestors()) {
        System.out.println("  " + ancestor.getName() + " "
                + ancestor.getDate() + " -" + ancestor.getDeathdate());
        System.out.println("    " + ancestor.getDad().getName());
        System.out.println("    " + ancestor.getMom().getName());
    }

    System.out.println();
}

public static void printDescendant(Person p) {
    System.out.println("DESCENDANTS of " + p.getName());
    for (Person descendant : p.getDescendants()) {
        System.out.println("  " + descendant.getName() + " "
                + descendant.getDate() + " -" + descendant.getDeathdate());

    }

}

private static void birth(String child, String date, String mother,
        String father) {

    Person mom = getPerson(mother);
    if (mom == null) {
        mom = new Person(null, null);
        mom.setName(mother);
    }
    Person dad = getPerson(father);
    if (dad == null) {
        dad = new Person(null, null);
        dad.setName(father);
    }

    Person childd = new Person(mom, dad);
    childd.setName(child);
    childd.setDate(date);

    persons.add(childd);

}

private static Person getPerson(String person) {
    for (Person p : persons) {
        if (p.getName().equals(person)) {
            return p;
        }

    }

    return null;
}

}
```

And this is my person class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Person {

private String name;
private String date;
private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();
private Person mom;
public boolean used = false;

private String deathDate = null;
private List<Person> ancestors = new ArrayList<Person>();
private List<Person> descendants = new ArrayList<Person>();


public Person getMom() {
    return mom;
}

private Person dad;
public Person getDad() {
    return dad;
}


public List<Person> getDescendants() {
    return descendants;
}

public List<Person> getAncestors() {
    return ancestors;
}

public Person(Person mom, Person dad)
{
    this.mom = mom;
    this.dad = dad;
}

public Person(String peo)
{
    name = peo;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setDate(String date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return this.date;
}

public void addChild(Person child)
{
    children.add(child);
}

public void kill(String date)
{
    this.deathDate = date;
}

public void addAncestors(Person p)
{
    ancestors.add(p);
}

public void addDescendants(Person p)
{
    descendants.add(p);
}

public String getDeathdate()
{
    if(this.deathDate == null)
        return "";
    else
        return " " + this.deathDate;
}


}
```

Comment: This happens, because you change the order of the persons that are added to your list and you just add both queries to a list of that person.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Alright how could I solve it so it's the same for the input? So that they don't have to be in that order to print ancestors first?

Comment: Add an (ordered) list to save these two queries and loop through it after the QUIT command (if you are not allowed to print the output directly).

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Alright I created an HashSet but i'm not quite sure how to add all the queries because I think you mean I should add all so I can print them out in an easy way. I'm not allowed to print the output directly after one command.

Comment: Another error in your code (at least if I understood the task correctly, the step 3 in Output) is that you limit the number of generations for ancestors/descendants to 2/1 respectively.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl What do you mean with numbers of generations for them to 2/1 respectively?

Comment: For example for descendants, you only print the first generation (1), if any the children have children themselves, you do ignore that, but the task says to repeat step 2-4 in step 3. For ancestors, you only print the first and second generation (2), even If a person only has one generation, and more are ignored.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl yeah that's true, maybe that's what's wrong right now. How can I fix that though? Because it feels like I'm repeating the steps now with the for-loops in the print methods now etc.

Comment: This is a little complicated to fully explain in a comment, but here are some hints: You can do this either iterative or recursive, where recursive might be easier here, since the algorithm described in the task is recursive. Then for starters implement each step in a single method, which calls the correct next method, depending on the current state. The state for example consists of the current ancestor and the generation count (for correctly intending lines).

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Alright but when you write starters, do you mean like the sample input on the assignment right now?

Comment: Fir starters means how you could start. But as I said, its hard just to describe, since its not really possible to post code in a comment. Since I implemented this task myself, take a look here: http://pastebin.com/6HpqzGTp

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Okok if I just wanna try if that one works, the things I comment out in my code will be the two print methods and the two else-if with ancestors and descendants? Or in the else-if I call the method processOutput() for example?

Comment: I posted this code to give you an example on how to implement the algorithm, described in the task, recursively for descendants. I posted the
    <code>processOutput()</code> 
method simply to provide a little context on how the 
<code>buildDescendantsTree()</code> 
is called/used. Since you seem to have great problems you should try to isolate the problems and work on them one by one and when you need help again you can ask here again, since this discussion is not really related to the question anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the order of the commands you need to save them somewhere.

For example you could create a class, since you already parse it:

```
public class OutputQuery
{
    public final String command;
    public final String name;

    // Add other fields..

    public OutputQuery(String command, String name)
    {
        this.command = command;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And in your main class you add a List and add them to it:

```
private static List<OutputQuery>    queries = new LinkedList<>();

// ...

else if (firstLine.contains("ANCESTORS"))
{
    String name = splitted[0].substring(10);

    queries.add(new OutputQuery("ANCESTORS", name));

    //...

else if (firstLine.contains("DESCENDANTS"))
{
    String name = splitted[0].substring(12);

    queries.add(new OutputQuery("DESCENDANTS", name));

    //...

else if (firstLine.contains("QUIT"))
{
    for (OutputQuery query : queries)
    {
        if (query.command == "ANCESTORS")
        {
            // Print output
        } else if (query.command == "DESCENDANTS")
        {
            // Print output
        }
    }

//...
```

---

You don't need to iterate over all persons, just the queries, as you can see in the code above, the loop over the queries is NOT in another loop, here the complete else if block:

```
else if (firstLine.contains("QUIT"))
{
    for (OutputQuery query : queries)
    {
        Person p = getPerson(query.name);

        if (query.command == "ANCESTORS")
        {
            printAncestor(p);
        } else if (query.command == "DESCENDANTS")
        {
            printDescendant(p);
        }
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Alright then maybe like this: http://pastebin.com/vNjqat2X ? The time complexity for that will be n^2 though which isn't that good but. I saw now that that printed many other stuff: http://puu.sh/kJgPJ/44b1e575a0.png

Comment: See my updated answer. Of course you do NOT loop over all persons to print the queries, that's why you get the weird output, since you save the persons name in the query (command) class, why not use it?

Comment: yeah your right, I did that now and it printed them in the correct order. Thank you :)

Comment: It would be nice then, if you actually accept the answer (my old one too). you do that by clicking on the greyed out checkmark right next to the up/downvote field. See http://stackoverflow.com/tour